# Why 'scaleLinear' never used？ and Why I have to included as a <script d3.v4.js>？

Tags: d3.js, rollupjs

```
$ npm install d3-scale

$ npm install --save-dev rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015-rollup rollup-plugin-node-resolve
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼src/scripts/main.js

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 1200])
    .range([0, 500]);

console.log(yScale(1200)); // 500
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale"; 

export default {
  entry: 'src/scripts/main.js',
  dest: 'build/js/main.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
  ],
};
```

---

```
$ npm run build
```

> > rollup -c
>
> ⚠️   'scaleLinear' is imported from external module 'd3-scale' but
>   never used

**The following file was created automatically**

▼build/js/main.min.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([10, 1200])
.range([0, 500]);
console.log(yScale(1200)); // 500

}());
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="build/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

Browser access

・console log display　500

・There is no problem.

---

**But when I remove d3v4.js**

▼index.html

```
<script src="build/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

Browser access

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

---

**Why I have to included as a `<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>`？**

・Is there a way to avoid loading `<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>`?

・Why does not it work properly even if only d3 - scale is read?

---

2017/4/26

**How to include the node-resolve plugin so that Rollup could find the d3-scale source code to include it？**

▼rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  entry: 'src/scripts/main.js',
  dest: 'build/js/main.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    resolve({
     //I want to know what to write here
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that message because you're importing `scaleLinear` into your *config file*, rather than your app. Remove that line from the config file and you won't get the warning.

Strictly speaking, your `src/scripts/main.js` file should look like this:

```js
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';

var yScale = scaleLinear() // <-- note there's no `d3.`
    .domain([10, 1200])
    .range([0, 500]);

console.log(yScale(1200)); // 500
```

In that case, you may need to tweak your config file, depending on what you want to do:

### 1. Bundle d3-scale into your app (recommended)

If you wanted to actually include `d3-scale` and its dependencies in the bundle Rollup creates so that you don't need to load D3 as a separate `<script>` tag, you would need to include the [node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) plugin so that Rollup could find the `d3-scale` source code to include it.

**This is what you'll need to do if you don't want to include D3 from unpkg.com.**

### 2. Tell Rollup what d3-scale is

At the moment your app works because `window.d3` is assigned to D3. That's totally fine and will work (you wouldn't even need the `import` declaration at all), but if you wanted to use the more idiomatic ES module approach without bundling `d3-scale` then you would need to add the following to your config:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  entry: 'src/scripts/main.js',
  dest: 'build/js/main.min.js',
  format: 'iife',

  // tell Rollup that d3-scale is an external package
  // and that it corresponds to `window.d3`
  external: ['d3-scale'],
  globals: {
    'd3-scale': 'd3'
  },

  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: First I trying "1. Bundle d3-scale into your app".I added question.How to include the node-resolve plugin so that Rollup could find the d3-scale source code to include it？

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass any options at all — `resolve()` by itself should work in d3-scale's case